# In log4net, should be output for a named logger also go to the default appender?

Tags: .net, log4net

If I have log4net configured as below

```
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>

    <logger name="MyNamespace.MyClass">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </logger>
```

I would like the output from the named class to end up only in the sql database (via the adoNetAppender) and **not** in both the sql database and the log file (via the rollingfileappender).

Is there a way of achieving that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the additivity attribute on logger to false. From [the documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html):

> Set this attribute to false to prevent
>   this logger from inheriting the
>   appenders defined on parent loggers.

```
<logger name="MyNamespace.MyClass" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</logger>
```